# How to derive the following formula for the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I came across the following theorem:

Let $A$ be a nonsingular square $p \times p$ matrix and $z$ be a p-dimensional column vector. The matrix $(A - z z^T)^{-1}$ is given by

$$(A- zz^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} + \frac{A^{-1}zz^TA^{-1}}{1-z^T A^{-1}z}$$

Now I tried using $A-zz^T$ multiply the matrix on the right side of the above formula and I cannot obtain an identity matrix. I tried:

$$(A^{-1} + \frac{A^{-1}zz^TA^{-1}}{1-z^T A^{-1}z})(A-zz^T) = I - A^{-1}zz^T - \frac{1}{1-z^TA^{-1}z}(A^{-1}zz^T+A^{-1}zz^TA^{-1}zz^T)$$

This is where I got stuck. Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: What you are doing is verification, not derivation.

Comment: How about a reasonable title?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Of course it's a valid proof on paper, but how come I get the expression for $Y$ in the first place? It doesn't seem that trivial does it?Even the wiki article on Sherman-Morrison formula mentions it merely as a verification.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It says so in the title. Anyway, I said what I was taught by my teacher. It's not a big deal.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ohhhh. I hadn't noticed the title. Now I see your point. Sorry for being so slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it! There's a small typo in your formula: the last term should be
$$
{}+ \frac{1}{1-z^TA^{-1}z}(A^{-1}zz^T-A^{-1}zz^TA^{-1}zz^T).
$$
And notice this equals
$$
\frac{1}{1-z^TA^{-1}z} \big( A^{-1}z ( 1 - z^TA^{-1}z) z^T \big),
$$
which should get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 3):

It is a particular case of Sherman-Morrison theorem

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)

with $u=z$ and $v=-z$.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that matrix multiplication is associative meaning $(AB)C = A(BC)$ so that

$$(A^{-1}zz^T)(A^{-1}zz^T) =  A^{-1}z(z^TA^{-1}z)z^T = (z^TA^{-1}z).A^{-1}zz^T$$

Notice that the last equality is due to the fact that $z^TA^{-1}z$ is a scalar.
Going back to your equality we now have:

$$
\begin{alignat}{}
(A^{-1} + \frac{A^{-1}zz^TA^{-1}}{1-z^T A^{-1}z})(A-zz^T) &&= I - A^{-1}zz^T + \frac{1}{1-z^TA^{-1}z}(A^{-1}zz^T - A^{-1}zz^TA^{-1}zz^T) \\\\&&= I - A^{-1}zz^T +  \frac{1}{1-z^TA^{-1}z}(A^{-1}zz^T - (z^TA^{-1}z).A^{-1}zz^T) \\\\&&= I - A^{-1}zz^T +  \frac{A^{-1}zz^T}{1-z^TA^{-1}z}(1 - (z^TA^{-1}z)) \\\\&&= I
\end{alignat}
$$